# BackUp for GKE prior to version 1.24.4-gke.800

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I was going through the documentation for creating backups for GKE cluster.
My cluster version in **1.21.14-gke.700** and in the docs it is written

> Caution: Backup for GKE requires full privileges to read and write
> every object in the cluster. The Backup for GKE agent that runs in GKE
> cluster versions prior to 1.24 runs as a workload in the GKE user
> cluster. Users or workloads with root access to the underlying node on
> which the Backup for GKE pod is scheduled, such as through pod
> hostpath mounts or SSH, can gain these root-in-cluster privileges. To
> avoid this potential node to cluster escalation, we highly recommend
> that you run Backup for GKE in GKE clusters running version
> 1.24.4-gke.800 or higher, where the agent runs on an inaccessible host in the GKE control plane.

Can anyone help me to explain the meaning of node to cluster escalation term in detail.
Also, what's the harm of running backups for GKE cluster prior to 1.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the GKE backup on GKE versions before 1.24. The backup agent runs as a privileged workloads on your cluster nodes. A privileged pod is a container that has root access on the node. that what we mean by "node to cluster escalation".

After 1.24 the agent runs in a dedicated namespace with a dedicated Service Account which has limited access.

Comment: What are the harms/repercussions of having a privileged workload in the k8s cluster ?

Comment: privileged workload represent a risk in general in k8s. The less of them you have the better it is. But as anything with security you have to balancer risk and benefits.

Comment: So, what should be the ideal way if one wants to create backup for GKE version prior to 1.24 ?

Comment: You can still use the Backup for GKE. Our documentation is just warning you about how it works and what are the risks. Sorry i cannot provide any recommandations over stackoverflow as i don't know your requirements!

Comment: No worries @boredabdel. I have a followup question acc. to my use-case. 
I have created a backup plan for my cluster and now I want to delete that cluster and restore it's applications on to some another cluster. 
But, I have a question here - 
Deleting the cluster will delete the corresponding backup agent. 
Will I still be able to restore my deleted cluster applications into an another live cluster

Comment: The agent is just used to perform the backup. The data is backed up somewhere else. I haven't try to do the thing you are trying to do. So i would say give it a try and see if it works

Comment: But, If I will delete the cluster and am unable to restore it, all my applications would be lost.
Also, deleting the Cluster deletes the corresponding backup plans too?